# Replace content of response in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

I wounder if it is possible to replace some of the content in a Servlet Filter, Using Spring Boot.

What i want to do is in some java-script files have variables, i can replace dependent on what environment i am using.

Or possible if this functionality already exists, have tried to find but been unsuccessful.

Comment: I would use different javascript assets per environment rather than changing them on the fly.

Comment: Most likely not, some of the response may already have been send to the client.

Comment: Nonsense @BoristheSpider, you can do anything you want in a Filter. The filter has complete control of what Request and Response objects it sends to the Servlet, and the Request and Response objects project the view of the connection to the Servlet.

Comment: @WillHartung yes, of course. I meant that you cannot replace content after the fact. You would have to set up some sort of output stream decorator.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example of modifying the entity of a response using Java Servlets.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html#72674) You could use the syntax `${name.of.prop}` in your javascript files, then do a string `replace` with values corresponding to that name.

Comment: Thanks, looks like exactly what i wanted :)